# Show initial value for FileField in django-template

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `ModelForm` whose all field's initial value is being displayed correctly in the template except the `FileField`. I want to display the initial value for that field too in the same way as displayed in the `django-admin`(with `currently` and `clear` checkbox). How do I do this ?

Models.py

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    profile_picture = models.FileField(upload_to=profile_image_upload, null=True, blank=True)

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = ['profile_picture', 'phone']
```

views.py

```
data = {
        'profile_picture' : user_detail.profile_picture,
        'phone' : user_detail.phone,
    }

    context["form"] = EditProfileForm(data)
```

Now when I do `{{form}}`, the initial value for `phone` is displayed correctly, but nothing for `profile_picture`. It says, `No file chosen`.

How do I show current current-file path and the clear checkbox as in django-admin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ModelForm then why not take advantage that to display.?

```
form = EditProfileForm(instance=your_user_profile_instance)
return render(request, 'test.html', {'form':form})
```

or

```
context["form"] = EditProfileForm(initial=data)
```

Comment: That worked, doing `context["form"] = EditProfileForm(initial = data)` worked too !

Comment: what if i am using only forms.Form then how can i do it thank you in advance .

Comment: Hi @Dexter I think you can pass as the dict to the `CustomForm(dict)` without initial keyword. Hope it will work. Let me know for the further assistance.